# What are PowerShell profile locations on Linux?

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

On Windows, not counting ISE or x86, there are four (4) profile scripts.

```
AllUsersAllHosts @ C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost @ C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts @ C:\Users\lit\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost @ C:\Users\lit\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

On Linux with pwsh 6.2.0 I can find only two locations.

```
CurrentUserAllHosts @ ~/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost @ ~/.config/powershell/profile.ps1
```

Are there any "AllUsers" profile scripts on Linux? If so, where are they?

Comment: Did you ask Powershell for it `$profile | Select-Object -Property *` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** (also applies to Windows):

- The conceptual [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) help topic describes PowerShell's profiles (initialization files).
- The [automatic `$PROFILE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#profile) contains a *string* that is the path of the initialization file for the *current user* and the *current PowerShell host environment* (typically, the terminal a.k.a console).
- *Additional* profile files are defined - along the dimensions of (a) all-users vs. current-user and (b) all host environments vs. the current one  - which are exposed via properties that the `$PROFILE` string variable is *decorated* with, which makes them nontrivial to discover - see below.
- None of the profile files exist *by default*, and in some case even their *parent directories* may not; the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408793/45375) shows programmatic on-demand creation and updating of the `$PROFILE` file.

---

[Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) provided the crucial pointer in comment:

```sh
$PROFILE | select *  # short for: $profile | Select-Object -Property *
```

shows *all* profile file locations, *whether or not the individual profile files exist*.

E.g., on my Ubuntu machine with PowerShell installed in `/home/jdoe/.powershell`, I get:

```sh
AllUsersAllHosts       : /home/jdoe/.powershell/profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : /home/jdoe/.powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : /home/jdoe/.config/powershell/profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : /home/jdoe/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Length                 : 62
```

<sup>Note the presence of the `[string]` type's native `Length` property, which you could omit if you used 
`$PROFILE | select *host*` instead.</sup>

That you can get the profile locations that way is not obvious, given that `$PROFILE` is a *string* variable (type `[string]`).
PowerShell decorates that `[string]` instance with `NoteProperty` members reflecting all profile locations, which is why `select` (`Select-Object`) is able to extract them.

Outputting just `$PROFILE` - i.e. the *string value* - yields `/home/jdoe/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, i.e. the same path as its `CurrentUserCurrentHost` property, i.e. the path of the user-specific profile file specific to the current PowerShell host environment (typically, the terminal aka console).<sup>[1]</sup>

You can verify the presence of these properties with reflection as follows, (which reveals their values too):

```sh
$PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty
```

This means that **you can also use *regular property access* and *tab completion* to retrieve individual profile locations**; e.g.:

```sh
# Use tab-completion to find a specific profile location.
# Expands to .Length first, then cycles through the profile-location properties.
$profile.<tab>  

# Open the all-users, all-hosts profiles for editing.
# Note: Only works if the file already exists.
#       Also, you must typically run as admin to modify all-user profiles.
Invoke-Item $profile.AllUsersAllHosts
```

---

#### Convenience functions for getting profile locations and opening profiles for editing:

The code below defines:

- `Get-Profile` enumerates profiles, showing their location and whether they exist on a given machine.
- `Edit-Profile` opens profile(s) for editing (use `-Force` to create them on demand); note that modifying all-user profiles typically requires running as admin.

```sh
function Get-Profile {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Gets the location of PowerShell profile files and shows whether they exist.
  #>
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
  param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [ValidateSet('AllUsersAllHosts', 'AllUsersCurrentHost', 'CurrentUserAllHosts', 'CurrentUserCurrentHost')]
    [string[]] $Scope
  )
  
  if (-not $Scope) {
    $Scope = 'AllUsersAllHosts', 'AllUsersCurrentHost', 'CurrentUserAllHosts', 'CurrentUserCurrentHost'
  }

  foreach ($thisScope in $Scope) {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Scope = $thisScope
      FilePath = $PROFILE.$thisScope
      Exists = (Test-Path -PathType Leaf -LiteralPath $PROFILE.$thisScope)
    }
  }

}

function Edit-Profile {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Opens PowerShell profile files for editing. Add -Force to create them on demand.
  #>
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false, DefaultParameterSetName='Select')]
  param (
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='Select')]
    [ValidateSet('AllUsersAllHosts', 'AllUsersCurrentHost', 'CurrentUserAllHosts', 'CurrentUserCurrentHost')]
    [string[]] $Scope = 'CurrentUserCurrentHost'
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All')]
    [switch] $All
    ,
    [switch] $Force
  )
  begin {
    $scopes = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string]
    if ($All) {
      $scopes = 'AllUsersAllHosts', 'AllUsersCurrentHost', 'CurrentUserAllHosts', 'CurrentUserCurrentHost'
    }
  }  
  process {
    if (-not $All) { $scopes.Add($Scope) }
  }

  end {
    $filePaths = foreach ($sc in $scopes) { $PROFILE.$sc }
    $extantFilePaths = foreach ($filePath in $filePaths) {
      if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $filePath)) {
        if ($Force) {
          if ((New-Item -Force -Type Directory -Path (Split-Path -LiteralPath $filePath)) -and (New-Item -Force -Type File -Path $filePath)) {
              $filePath
          }
        } else {
          Write-Verbose "Skipping nonexistent profile: $filePath"
        }
      } else {
        $filePath
      }
    }
    if ($extantFilePaths.Count) {
      Write-Verbose "Opening for editing: $extantFilePaths"
      Invoke-Item -LiteralPath $extantFilePaths
    } else {
      Write-Warning "The implied or specified profile file(s) do not exist yet. To force their creation, pass -Force."
    }
  }

}
```

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell considers the current-user, current-host profile *the* profile of interest, which is why `$PROFILE`'s *string value* contains that value. Note that in order to decorate a `[string]` instance with note properties, `Add-Member` alone is not enough; you must use the following idiom: `$decoratedString = $string | Add-Member -PassThru propName propValue` - see the [`Add-Member` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member).</sup>