# VS code terminal can't find AWS SAM even though windows terminal can

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, aws-sam-cli, path-variables

I installed AWS SAM from the msi installer from AWS for windows.
after running the installer, I ran `sam --version` in cmd and powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\dgupta> sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.26.0
```

It returns the version I just installed. However in VS code, I opened a terminal and ran `sam --version` it errors out.

```console
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

sam : The term 'sam' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,                                                                                                               g of the name,    
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sam --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sam:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

why is this happening ? doesn't VS Code terminal and normal terminal have access to the same environment variables ?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly fixed it, I think its docker related. the sam command couldnt be found. so I deleted and reinstalled docker. edited the path for python.exe in the path variable. re-installed SAM and instead of restarting the computer, I turned it off and started it without the windows updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impossible to diagnose your problem without further information, but perhaps these **troubleshooting tips** help:

If **invoking an *external executable* (`sam`) by *name only* fails**, the **problem must be that the directory in which the executable resides isn't listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable** defined for the current process.

However, **it is possible that the external `sam` executable's directory *isn't* in `$env:PATH` and that `sam` is an auxiliary *PowerShell command* of the same name** that knows the true `sam`'s location and invokes it behind the scenes.
For instance an *alias* - such as `New-Alias sam 'C:\path\to\sam.exe'` - or a *function* - such as `function sam { & C:\path\to\sam.exe $args }` - could be defined.

From the PowerShell session where `sam` *is* found:

- To **determine what type of command the name `sam` refers to** in your session, use the following and check the value of the `CommandType` column:

```bash
Get-Command sam
```

- If the **command type is `Application`**, you are indeed dealing with an *external executable*, and **the `Source` column will report its *full path***, from which you can glean the executable's *directory* path (which you can determine directly with `Split-Path (Get-Command -Type Application sam).Path`

  - You then need to **diagnose why that directory *isn't* in `$env:PATH`** in the other session - see first section below.
- If the **command type *isn't* `Application`**:

  - You need to **determine where the auxiliary alias or function is defined** and why your other session doesn't see it, which, if the problem is reproducible in new sessions, **must be connected to what [*profile files*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)** (as reflected in the [automatic `$PROFILE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#profile)) **were loaded**.

---

**Diagnose why a directory is missing from `$env:PATH` *on Windows*:**<sup>[1]</sup>

Possible reasons:

- You've just installed an executable, and the installer modified the *persistent* `$env:PATH` definition *in the registry*.

  - Any running processes started *before* this modification or even ones started afterwards *directly from such processes*, i.e. as child processes, do *not* see the modification.
  - Solution:

    - **Start a *new* session**, which in your case means restarting Visual Studio Code, but **be sure to start it from the Start Menu / taskbar / File Explorer, as they *are* aware of the modified environment**. When in doubt, log off and back on to your Windows session, or reboot your machine.
    - Alternatively, refresh `$env:PATH` from the registry in-session - see below.
- Something in your current PowerShell session has (possibly inadvertently) removed `sam`'s directory from the in-process `$env:PATH` variable.

  - Solution:

    - **Refresh the in-process `$env:PATH` definition from the registry** with the following command (note that any prior in-process modifications are then lost):

```bash
$env:PATH = 
  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine') + ';' +
  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')
```

---

If these solutions don't help (persistently), the problem must be :

- Either: Even the *persistent* `Path` variable definition is lacking an entry for the directory or interest (even though installers normally do add such an entry).
- Or: The problem arises from what PowerShell [*profile files*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) are loaded into the different environments.
  For instance, if a given profile file adds a relevant `$env:PATH` entry dynamically to every session, a different environment, such as Visual Studio Code, may not load the same profile file.

See the next sections.

---

**Add a directory entry to the persistent definition of the `Path` environment variable yourself, *on Windows*:**<sup>[1]</sup>

- **If you don't know *which directory* to add to the `Path` variable**, you can locate it via a command such as the following:

  ```bash
  # Find the directory/ies on drive C: that contain a "sam.exe" file.
  Get-ChildItem C:\ -Filter sam.exe -Recurse -File -ErrorAction Ignore | 
    ForEach-Object DirectoryName
  ```
- **Interactively**:

  - Run `sysdm.cpl`, select the `Advanced` tab, and click on `Environment Variables...`, then modify the `Path` variable as desired.:

    - Note: To modify the `Path` variable under `System variables`, i.e. the *system-wide* part of the `Path` variable, you need to be an *administrator*.
    - After having modified `Path` this way, you need to open a *new* shell session in the manner described above in order to see the effects.
- **Programmatically**:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) for helper function `Add-Path`; the answer also explains why `set.exe` should *not* be used.

---

**Diagnose what *profile files* were loaded into a session, on *all platforms*:**

PowerShell's [*profile files*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) are (by default) loaded (dot-sourced) on session startup and allow sessions to be customized, which can include things such as custom alias definitions, functions, and even in-process `$env:PATH` additions.

There are *multiple* profile files, *all* of which are loaded (by default), if present, along two independent dimensions: all-users vs. current-user, and all-hosts vs. current-host (a host being the PowerShell host environment, such as a regular console window or the terminal in Visual Studio Code).

The [automatic `$PROFILE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#profile) reports the current-user, current-host profile-file path, but actually has normally invisible properties listing *all* paths (you can make them visible with `$PROFILE | select *` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561454/45375)).

**What profiles are loaded** into a session for a given user is determined by the following factors:

- Fundamentally, whether profile loading is *suppressed* altogether, using the CLI's `-NoProfile` switch.
- If *not* suppressed (the default, even with `-Command` and `-File` invocations):

  - What *edition* of PowerShell you're using: The comes-with Windows, legacy, Windows-only *Windows PowerShell* edition (whose latest and *final* version is 5.1), whose CLI is [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), vs. the install-on-demand, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition, whose CLI is [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), have *separate* profile locations.
  - The type of the host environment, as reflected in the [automatic `$Host` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#host).

To **see what command line was used to invoke the current session**, run the following:

```bash
[Environment]::CommandLine
```

Note:

- In the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) (which runs in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal) you'll *always* see `-NoProfile` among the parameters, but profiles may still be loaded during startup - see below.

It follows from the above that different host environments load different sets of profile files, and in the **PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console)** that comes with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) and which runs in **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)'s integrated terminal**, ***different* profile files are indeed loaded**, IF enabled via the `PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading` setting - compared to regular console windows<sup>[2]</sup>

**If you want your PIC sessions to load the same current-user profile as regular console windows:**

- Via Visual Studio Code's settings, first make sure that the `PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading` setting is *enabled* and start a new PIC session, if necessary.
- From a PIC session, run `psedit $PROFILE` to open the host-specific current-user profile for editing.
- Add the following content:

```bash
. ($PROFILE -replace '\.VSCode', '.PowerShell')
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that *Unix*-like platforms have *no* standardized mechanism for defining *persistent* environment variables, which is why neither PowerShell nor .NET provide APIs for it.</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that you can use PowerShell in the Visual Studio Code terminal even *without* the PowerShell extension, as a *general-purpose shell*, and such session *do* use the same profiles as regular console windows - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132705/45375).</sup>

Comment: I'm trying to follow the instructions for "If you want your PIC sessions to load the same current-user profile as regular console windows:"  - but if I add the contents to replace profile it just seems to leave my new PIC sessions in a state where they are unusable and hang without ending up on a command prompt.

Comment: @mutex, I encourage you to ask a new question focused on your specific problem.