# az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet - doesnt work from powershell but works on command prompt windows 10 Ps version 5

Tags: powershell

I have been testing code on my laptop recently, and this appears to be broken my az cli setup. I now get an error, I have followed the steps detailed on most SO pages which entail running the command

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; rm .\AzureCLI.msi`

AZ cli works on command prompt just not on powershell.

- I uninstalled az cli
- Restarted laptop
- Ran the command above which completed, again it works on command prompt just not on powershell.

Environment.

Windows 10
Ps version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      19041  1682

I suspect it is to do with the path profiles as the script I was running the other day was changing the path profile before I had to reboot the laptop.

I also found this instruction on another SO page. ran this to no avail.

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Force Install-module AzureADPreview -Force Install-Module -Name MSOnline -Force Import-Module Az -Force Install-Module Az -Force
```

Comment: Try the troubleshooting steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mklement0, you definitely pointed me in the right direction.

I ran `$env:path` and this came up with `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin`
I can see the problem now, I resolved it by getting the values of my path variable from the GUI Advanced system settings >> Environment variables and copy the values of path.

from a PS console screen set the values for path by running the following.

```
$env:path = "the values from the path environment variables above"
```

After running the above, I can run az cli once more.