# Why can I only run the flutter command in admin mode? Windows 11

Tags: flutter, git, powershell, dart, cmd

I have git set in my PATH variables, but it shows the response "unable to find git in PATH". However, when I run "flutter doctor" in admin mode, it doesn't display that "unable to find git in PATH" message. It actually shows the flutter doctor command functioning.

PATH:

`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin`

`C:\Windows\System32`

None of these PATHs fixed the issue. I just want to be able to run the flutter command outside of admin mode.

Comment: Normal users do not have write access to those folders.  If you want normal users to be able to run your code than you have to create a shortcut and add the property to shortcut Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng, the question is about missing directories from `$env:Path`, resulting in the inability to _locate an executable_ by name only (`git`); it isn't about wanting to _write to_ those directories.

Comment: I've scoured the internet. No one knows. So I've raised the issue on the Flutter issues page: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123995.

Honestly I feel like I'm always the one to stumble across issues to do with basic usage whenever I try any programming tech. I should just get hired as a tester for everything given my luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your elevated (admin) sessions *with your own user identity*, you should see the *same* `$env:PATH` value (value of the `Path` environment variable) in your *non*-elevated sessions too.

Conceivably, you simply haven't yet started a *new* non-elevated session since the registry-based persistent definition of the `Path` environment variable was modified (such changes are never picked up *in-session*).

Therefore:

- Start a new (non-elevated) PowerShell session *via the taskbar or the Start Menu*.
- If that doesn't help, log off and log back in, or forcefully kill all Windows (GUI) shell processes with `Stop-Process -Force -Name explorer` before starting a new session.

A comprehensive troubleshooting guide for `$env:PATH` issues can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue even after setting the paths. I tried this code. Try to run this command on your cmd panel

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

Hope it works,
Thank you