# Error: Unable to find git in your PATH with FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, git, powershell, command-line

Whenever I run the flutter or dart commands on the command line or PowerShell I get "Error: Unable to find Git in your PATH".

I've already tried to the solutions from other suggestions like making sure the PATH contains:

1. C:\Windows\System32
2. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
3. C:\Program Files\Git\bin and/or C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
4. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
5. C:\src\flutter\bin

I reinstalled flutter and still does the same.

I reinstalled Git and tried it on the command line and Git works.

I'm using VS Code and Windows 11, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` PATH must be a list of directories, not files!

Comment: @phd Yes, I know the PATH is an environment variable which contains a string of text holding a list of directories separated by semicolons and are not files, however I wanted to try C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe because I've seen it like that in other suggestions, I did get rid of it afterwards.

Comment: What does `Get-Command git -All` report in your VS Code PowerShell session? Does `$env:Path` report a different value than `path` in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @mklement0 Check the image I added, you'll see to see the response to your questions... $env:Path and %path% have the same value.

Comment: Mysterious - I'm out of ideas. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375) offers methodical troubleshooting tips, but I'm not sure it has something to offer that you haven't already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Adding paths to `Path`(System variables):

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\src\flutter\bin
```

helped solve the problem.

-> Also, try rebooting the computer for the changes to take effect

-> Run cmd/PowerShell/Android Studio as administrator

Moreover, I use the git portable version.

Comment: @Ruble I've already added the paths to PATH... I use VS Code... I'm running the flutter and dart commands from VS Code and from the command line and/or powershell... I rebooted the computer and still get the error... You use the portable version of what?

Comment: @phd Yes, I know the PATH holds a list of directories not files.

Comment: It was meant that the git is installed portable...