# Unable to run az command on vs code terminal

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

When I type "az --version" on powershell, its showing me the current version. But when I type the same in the vs code terminal, it output an error saying "az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I have installed all the required Azure cli extension on VS code, also I have set the environment variables on my local machine.

Comment: Without additional information, your problem cannot be diagnosed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375) contains detailed troubleshooting steps. If they help you solve your problem, we can close your question as a duplicate. If you've tried everything there and it still doesn't work, please provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

***Need to check below:***

- Check that the Azure CLI tools extension is properly installed in Visual Studio Code. When the extensions fail in the middle, the az command will stop working.
- Go to settings and search terminal integrated shell as shown below. Check that the shell integration is enabled and the specific shell you've chosen is compatible with the Azure CLI versions.

[image]

After a workaround on this issue, I found a way to run CLI files in the Visual Studio Code by activating the **"virtual environment".**

Detailed steps given here for the [Virtual env](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) activation.

Once it is activated, install the `Azure CLI` package using `pip`.

```
pip install azure-cli
```

[image]

Once the installation done successfully, I created a file with the `.azcli` extension and executed it by going to `command palette -> search for run line in terminal`. It worked for me as expected.

[image]

*To leave your virtual environment, use the `deactivate` command in the terminal.*

*If still the issue persists, restart & update the Vscode for the better functionality.*