# Powershell Doesn't Identify Git Commands Even With Environment Variable

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code, path-variables

My Power Shell does not recognize the "git" command at all even after I have reinstalled my Windows 10 after deleting my environment variable and not even after I have reinstalled Git. The environment variable path that Git uses is `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`. I don't know if it has anything to do with it. Power Shell says it doesn't recognize "git" as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I already tried to check if there was a similar problem on the internet, but the proposed solutions did not help me.

Comment: Without additional information, your problem cannot be diagnosed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375) contains detailed troubleshooting steps. If they help you solve your problem, we can close your question as a duplicate. If you've tried everything there and it still doesn't work, please provide more information.

Comment: Hello friend. I already managed to solve the problem, but without knowing how. What I can tell you is that it has to do with the Path system environment variable. I checked and saw that there are the following paths:

%SystemRoot%\system32 - 
%SystemRoot% - 
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem - 
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ - 
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd - 
C:\src\flutter\bin. Thank you for your willingness to respond. But what additional information would you need to answer this question? The ones I put weren't enough in what way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error when I type in what you did on my Powershell, even though my `git` command works. Have you tried entering this command? This works for me since it directly calls the `git` application within the `cmd` directory.

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git'
```

For others on the Internet, the ampersand `&` is to let Powershell know that the inside of the string is the command you want to run, which is helpful for computer commands where there may be a space in a directory name.

Comment: Sure, invocation by full path is an option - but inconvenient; adding a program's directory to `$env:PATH` is meant to avoid this inconvenience, and is definitely a solvable problem. If all else fails or you don't want to modify `$env:PATH`, you can get the same convenience with an _alias_, which - if put in the `$PROFILE` file - allows you to refer to Git just by `git` as well: `New-Alias git 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe'`

Comment: Hello friend. I already managed to solve the problem, but without knowing how. What I can tell you is that it has to do with the Path system environment variable. I checked and saw that there are the following paths: %SystemRoot%\system32 - %SystemRoot% - %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem - %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd. I realize that operations on the Path system environment variable can carry a lot of risk. Thank you for your willingness to respond.