# PowerShell reports " The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: windows, git, powershell

```
PS C:\Users\akira> git 

git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried setting the environment variables and everything worked fine, but the problem still appears

Comment: where is `git` supposed to be installed? how did you install it? is it embedded in WSL2 or did you install some native Windows version?

Comment: Without additional information, your problem cannot be diagnosed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375) contains detailed troubleshooting steps for problems related to locating executables via the `PATH` environment variable. If they help you solve your problem, we can close your question as a duplicate. If you've tried everything there and it still doesn't work, please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you already added GIT executable to the $env.path environment variable, close the window and re-open.  The command window loads the environment on load, it does not hot-reload if the environment changed while the command window was open.

Answer (score -3):

Check the git version you have installed on your system

```
git --version
```

It seems that git is not installed.