# How to change the current directory using .bat file in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am learning Windows PowerShell and I am struggling with the very basic task, how to create a .bat file to change the current directory? The simple .bat file with `cd mydir` inside worked well using `cmd.exe`, but it does not work in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\ET\test> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\ET\test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        01/10/2021     10:57                mydir
-a----        01/10/2021     10:58             10 changeDir.bat


PS C:\Users\ET\test> type changeDir.bat
cd mydir
PS C:\Users\ET\test> .\changeDir.bat

C:\Users\ET\test>cd mydir
PS C:\Users\ET\test>
```

You see that my current directory has not changed after executing the .bat file.
Works as expected using `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\Users\ET\test>changeDir

C:\Users\ET\test>cd mydir

C:\Users\ET\test\mydir>
```

Comment: Why don't you use PowerShell scripts and commands when using Powershell instead of `cmd` commands and scripts? The Powershell command for changing the working folder is `Set-Location`

Comment: Thank you, Set-Location works fine from the command line, but script execution is disabled by default, and I am not using elevated PowerShell.

Comment: Evgeniy, you state that script execution is disabled, is computer a standalone or connected to a network where the Administrator has disabled script execution? If it is a standalone computer you can just use the Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned command from an admin level powershell console to fix that and it's a one time command.

Comment: Based on your [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404268/how-to-change-the-current-directory-using-bat-file-in-windows-powershell#comment122675625_69404463) I would advise you to use Powershell's ALIAS or FUNCTIONS capability.  You could even do it by creating a DOSKEY Macro that is executed within Powershell.

Comment: Would also like to point out that if you have a directory opened in Windows Explorer and want to open up PowerShell to that directory, all you have to do is type `powershell` in the path bar.  This also works for cmd.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because a batch file (`.bat`, `.cmd`) runs in a *child process* (via `cmd.exe`), you fundamentally cannot change *PowerShell's* current directory with it**.

- This applies to *all* calls that run in a child process, i.e. to all external-program calls and calls to scripts interpreted by a scripting engine other than PowerShell itself.
- While the *child process*' working directory is changed, this has no effect on the *caller* (parent process), and there is no built-in mechanism that would allow a given process to change its parent's working directory (which would be a treacherous feature).

The next best thing is to **make your `.bat` file *echo (output)* the path of the desired working directory and pass the result to PowerShell's [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) cmdlet**.

```sh
# Assuming that `.\changeDir.bat` now *echoes* the path of the desired dir.
Set-Location -LiteralPath (.\changeDir.bat)
```

A simplified example that simulates output from a batch file via a `cmd /c` call:

```sh
Set-Location -LiteralPath (cmd /c 'echo %TEMP%')
```

---

**If you're looking for a short convenience command that navigates to a given directory**, do not use a batch file - **use a *PowerShell* script or function** instead; e.g.:

```sh
function myDir { Set-Location -LiteralPath C:\Users\ET\test\myDir }
```

Executing `myDir` then navigates to the specified directory.

You can **add this function to your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)**, so as to automatically **make it available in *future* sessions too**.

You can open `$PROFILE` in your text editor or add the function programmatically, as follows, which ensures on-demand creation of the file and its parent directory:

```sh
# Make sure the $PROFILE file exists.
If (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { $null = New-Item -Force $PROFILE }

# Append the function definition to it.
@'

function myDir { Set-Location -LiteralPath C:\Users\ET\test\myDir }
'@ | Add-Content $PROFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
Write-host "running in directory $dir"
```

Comment: Frankly. I do not understand the code above, sorry.

Comment: i thought you have a finished script and would like to work from the script directory

Comment: My task is much simpler. When I start PowerShell it always starts in my home directory. I need to quickly jump to my working directory and I bored typing every time cd command with quite a long path.

Comment: As an aside: In PSv3+ `$PSScriptRoot` directly contains the directory in which the enclosing script is located.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a way to start PowerShell in the directory I need. For that, I am using Windows Terminal app https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701. I've configured the settings.json file this way:

```
        "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
        "name": "PowerShell",
        "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore",
        "startingDirectory": "C:\\Haskell\\HaskellWikiBook"
```