# How to load variables automatically in PowerShell for every session?

Tags: powershell

In Unix we have this `~/.bash_profile` file where we can load variables every time we open a terminal. How can I do it in Powershell without admin rights? I mean, it is just my profile. I want to automatically set the proxy variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` every time I open the PS terminal.

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate answers your question (which is Unix-focused, but applies analogously to Windows too). See also: [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)

Comment: @mklement0 is not for LInux, I want for Windows

Comment: It is only the specific paths that are Linux-specific in the linked post - even though the paths are different, all the information there applies to Windows too. If you want a Windows example that includes _programmatic_ creation of the `$PROFILE` file (a pitfall is that the _parent directory_ may need to be created too), see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408793/45375).